# When I test a method, do I trust that other methods work?

Tags: unit-testing

If I'm unit testing method A and I use a number of other methods (or property getters) in my test to check its behavior (I'm not using mocks in this case), is it good practice to trust that those other methods work properly and assume that if they don't it will be caught in tests on those methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should test only a single method/unit. For instance TestNG encourages you to make such an assumptions by allowing you to define test dependencies. If you test method `foo()` which depends on method `bar()`, make your test dependent on the one that tests `bar()`. If `bar()` test(s) fail, tests for `foo()` won't even run.

The downside of this assumption (when you don't have the ability to define test dependencies) is that when `bar()` method is broken, tests for both `foo()` and `bar()` will fail, making it harder to find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: that's a very cool feature and it seems like a very useful tool in organizing the testing processing.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes.

The very nature of unit testing is that you are verifying that some atomic "unit" of code produces the correct result in a series of known situations. The test should be performed as if in a vacuum; any code on which your unit depends should be spoofed (usually via a mock) to produce the expected inputs. Those dependencies should also have their own unit tests that will verify that they would produce those expected inputs to their dependents in the same situation.

Comment: I think I'm missing something.  I've always understood that the kinds of dependencies that should be mocked are external components, not methods within the same class.  If I mock methods in the same class what exactly am I testing?  In other words if I'm setting up literally everything to work as expected, won't everything work as expected by design?

Comment: A mock that overrides some methods but not others is a "partial mock". For instance, if you have an object with a method that performs some validation, then calls a second method in the class to write data to a file, you can create a partial mock that hijacks the data-writing method to just say "I did it" without actually touching the file system. This is pretty common when you have a single object, but some TDD/BDD guys would tell you that validation and file writing are seperate tasks that should go in seperate classes.

Comment: ... And yes, that is in fact the entire purpose of a unit test, to prove that code written to produce the expected behavior does so. Most simple examples would look stupid (prove that A + B == A + B), but the code you'd put in a method is rarely that simple. Also, code in a unit test CAN call other methods; the two basic restrictions are that that method NOT be in another class (you can mock that other class), and that that method not cause a "side effect" (like UI, filesystem, DB or network operations).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I guess I'm still not clear.  I understand the point of mocking out things like the system, UI, db, etc.  but if you, as you say, spoof any code on which a method depends what are you really checking beyond that the code works with fake code specifically designed to make the SUT pass a test. I'm not in any way criticizing, I'm confused at where to draw the line on mocking.

Comment: Think of it not as using "fake code specifically designed to make the SUT pass", think of it as "fake code specifically designed to give the SUT constant inputs so we can expect a deterministic result". 9 times out of 10, what you end up mocking is just the side-effect-producing code. However, mocks don't just stand in for real objects, they can actually test that dependent code is making the right calls. For instance, you can test a strategy pattern by mocking the factory methods used; if the wrong one is called by the strategy, the test fails.

Comment: I've reread your comments and original answer and they've resonated a lot more.  It seems to me you do indeed assume everything else works in the service of testing a given piece of functionality in isolation.  Two questions for you: (1) do you personally isolate down to the method level where you are mocking/stubbing out other method calls in the same class? (2) how do we then relax these assumptions that everything else works; is that where integration testing comes in?

Comment: Personally, I try to maintain a single-class restriction to unit-tested code, but very often I'll end up writing a unit test that ends up exercising multiple methods in the class. It depends on the architecture. When developing using TDD, your test may lead you towards a particular design, but you shouldn't write tests that verify that a particular design pattern is in use (because the test only makes sense in that case). That may mean that your test just exercises the "front door" to your code, while ensuring that no side effects occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you really distrust some other methods then you should write unit tests for those methods. Even if the bad method causes your unit test to fail, it will also fail its own unit test and this will lead the programmer to fix the right bug.